# How to combine Google Analytics and Google AdWords gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

**My Google Analytics code is:**

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-119899800-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-119899800-1');
</script>
```

**Google AdWords gives me the same code like:**

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google AdWords: 796207283 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-796207283"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'AW-796207283');
</script>
```

**Where & how to locate those code together?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should merge codes in this way:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-119899800-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-119899800-1');
    gtag('config', 'AW-796207283');
</script>
```

and insert it in `<head>` of pages you need.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en

Comment: Short and sweet! Would also recommend using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to insert standard GA and AW codes. Once you add your GTM container code to your template, you can manage your tags within GTM to give you more power and flexibility. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Comment: But what about this code: "<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-796207283"></script>"

Comment: @NafRifat See google support support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en. And here developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag is explanation: "This ID is specified when you receive a global tag (for example, from an AdWords account or from Google Analytics). The identifier in this line (i.e., the gtag.js identifier) does not determine which accounts will receive the data, but is used to uniquely identify the tag. Accounts that receive data from a tag are determined by calling the config command".